# install mysql without having internet nor cd/dvd iso on redhat

Tags: mysql, redhat

I want to install mysql server on a remote server but I haven't internet access and I haven't cd/dvd iso. Is it possible to download all mysql repository locally? 
Actually if I execute

```
    yum install mysql*
```

, I have this error :

```
 http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'repo.mysql.com'" Trying other mirror. Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: mysql-connectors-community. Please verify its path and try again
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the `rpm` command directly (something like `rpm -ivh *.rpm`) but you need to download manually all the packages involved and you'll be lucky if you don't need to upgrade many other packages).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the rpm of mysql and install it
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation-rpm.html

Answer (score 1):

Download this package ... if use redhat7 linux

**mariadb-5.5.44-2.el7.x86_64**

install package this command line

**#rpm -ivh mariadb-5.5.44-2.el7.x86_64**

i think this issue solve

Comment: Thanks very much. I downloaded packages  from the link you gave me and it works!